# Getting an overlay on a video to work using bootstrap and Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, overlay

I'm using Angular 6 and Bootstrap to try to get an image some text to 'appear' over a video element.  I've got most of what I'm looking for working except that I can't quite get the 'alignment' of the overlay to line up with the video element.  Instead it seems to be aligning with the overall 'page'.  I've tried a bunch of things (removing col and row classes, changing the position of the overlay in the code, writing custom classes etc. but after thrashing on this for a quite a while I think some gap in my knowledge is preventing me from making it happen.

Here is the html and css for the component...  Any advice would be sincerely appreciated.

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: display;
  /* Hidden by default */
  width: 50%;
  /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 50%;
  /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(58, 57, 57, 0);
  /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2;
  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add a pointer on hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 m-0 p-0">
    <video src="" class="embed-responsive-item" #video id="video" autoplay></video>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12" id="overlay" *ngIf="showRobot">
    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ezar-77f5e.appspot.com/o/roboguide3.png?alt=media&token=54655d7b-2cc1-41f4-8c2c-a7855db849f9" alt="" class="w-25" />
    <p>The result is: {{ myString }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of an element with `position: absolute`, depends of the first parent element with positioning relative.

So you should trying something like this:

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 m-0 p-0">
        <video src="" class="embed-responsive-item" #video id="video" autoplay></video>
        <div class="overlay-video" *ngIf="showRobot">
          <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ezar-77f5e.appspot.com/o/roboguide3.png?alt=media&token=54655d7b-2cc1-41f4-8c2c-a7855db849f9" alt="" class="w-25" />
          <p>The result is: {{ myString }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay-video{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(58, 57, 57, 0.8);
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Pay attention that the bootstrap 4 css class `.embed-responsive` already has the property `position: relative;`

DEMO:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8G8SQUia5FAZHpVygD2Q?p=preview

Comment: I am deeply thankful that there are smarter people than me on this planet.  Thanks so much manzapanza, your changes worked like a charm.  Also great to know for next time that embed-responsive already has position: relative.